# Error Python estructura de datos

Tags: python

Me encuentro realizando una refactorización de código y estoy probando algo y me da un error que no logro comprender:

```
 messageStruct = {
    "timestamp":"",
    "levels":"",
    "crons":"",
    "project":"",
    "application":"",
    "state":"",
    "lifespan":"",
    "environment":"",
    "event":""
}

def printPretty( inputMessageStruct ):
    return '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' % (inputMessageStruct.timestamp, inputMessageStruct.levels,inputMessageStruct.crons,
     inputMessageStruct.project, inputMessageStruct.application, inputMessageStruct.state, inputMessageStruct.lifespan, 
     inputMessageStruct.environment, inputMessageStruct.event)
```

Y me da el siguiente error...

```
return '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' % (inputMessageStruct.timestamp, inputMessageStruct.levels,inputMessageStruct.crons,
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'timestamp'
```

Comment: Los campos se accesan usando `[]`, asi `inputMessageStruct["timestamp"]`

Comment: Tienes razón no se en que estaba pensando.

Muchas garcias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es porque en Python a los valores de un diccionario se accede con la sintaxis `variable[clave]`.

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
def printPretty( inputMessageStruct ):
    return '%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s' % (inputMessageStruct["timestamp"], inputMessageStruct["levels"],inputMessageStruct["crons"],
     inputMessageStruct["project"], inputMessageStruct["application"], inputMessageStruct["state"], inputMessageStruct["lifespan"], 
     inputMessageStruct["environment"], inputMessageStruct["event"])
```